# Proof with orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, linear-transformations

I stuck at this problem:
I need to prove that for linear transformation $$T:R^n\to R^n$$ 
defined by $$T(x)=Px$$
such that $$P^T=T^{-1}$$
for any $x,y$ $$T(x) \cdot T(y)=x\cdot y$$
and also that $T$ is continuous.

I tried the straightforward approach taking columns of P as $u_1,...,u_n$ orthogonal vectors and tried to compute the dot product $Px\cdot Py$, but it was of no use as it didn't tell me anything.

Comment: The scalar product of $T(x)$ and $T(y)$ is $x^T P^T P y=x^T (P^T P) y=x^T y$. Linear and finite dimensional => continuous -- you can show this either by direct computation or by compactness of spheres.

Comment: Curious equation $P^T=T^{-1}$. Is that the same $T$ on both sides? Or should $T=P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as
$$x \cdot y = y^T x.$$

> Additional hint: So, how can we write $Px \cdot Py$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $P^T=P^{-1}$, then $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, which indicates that

> If $$E=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots\epsilon_n]$$
>   is an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^n$. 
>   Then
>   $$T(E)=[T(\epsilon_1),T(\epsilon_2),\cdots T(\epsilon_n)]=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots\epsilon_n]P=[\epsilon'_1,\epsilon'_2,\cdots\epsilon'_n]=E'$$ 
>   is also an orthonormal basis.

Consider any $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb R^n$
$$x=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots\epsilon_n] \left( \begin{array} \\x_1 \\x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_n \end{array} \right )=EX$$
$$y=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots\epsilon_n] \left( \begin{array} \\y_1 \\y_2 \\ \vdots \\y_n \end{array} \right )=EY$$
Then it is plain to see that
$$x\centerdot y=X^T Y$$
since $E$ is an orthonormal basis, under which the metric matrix will be identical matrix, thus making the inner product $x^T A y$ simplify to the best form $X^T Y$.
Then consider $T(x)$ and $T(y)$
$$T(x)=[T(\epsilon_1),T(\epsilon_2),\cdots T(\epsilon_n)] \left( \begin{array} \\x_1 \\x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_n \end{array} \right )=EPX=E'X$$
$$T(y)=[T(\epsilon_1),T(\epsilon_2),\cdots T(\epsilon_n)] \left( \begin{array} \\y_1 \\y_2 \\ \vdots \\y_n \end{array} \right )=EPY=E'Y$$
which also yields
$$T(x)\centerdot T(y)=X^T Y=x\centerdot y$$
since $E'$ is an orthonormal basis too.
QED.